# UTF-8 file appending in vbscript/classicasp - can it be done?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

My current knowledge:

If you are trying to write text files in vbscript / asp land you have two options.

> 1. the Scripting.FileSystemObject
> 2. the ADODB.Stream object

`Scripting.FileSystemObject` does not support utf8.  It will write in Ascii, or Unicode (and waste two bytes for most of your characters)

`ADODB.Stream` does not support appending (afaik).  I can't figure out how to make the `ADODB.Stream` object actually open a file and write to it when I call stream.Write.  There is a `SaveToFile` function, but it outputs the entire stream.

If you need to write 1GB files, you would have to fill the whole 1GB into the stream before you could write it out.

Is there a special trick to get the `ADODB.Stream` object to *link* to a file on disk?  I tried :

```
stream.Open "URL=file:///c:\test.txt"
```

but that gave an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this scenario, I would probably create a COM component that takes a string, and runs it through [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms776420(VS.85).aspx) to convert it to UTF-8.

In case you really want to stay *within* VBScript, I just hacked up a very quick and very dirty UTF-8 conversion...

```
Function Utf8(ByVal c)

    Dim b1, b2, b3

    If c < 128 Then
        Utf8 = chr(c)
    ElseIf c < 2048 Then
        b1 = c Mod 64
        b2 = (c - b1) / 64
        Utf8 = chr(&hc0 + b2) & chr(&h80 + b1)
    ElseIf c < 65536 Then
        b1 = c Mod 64
        b2 = ((c - b1) / 64) Mod 64
        b3 = (c - b1 - (64 * b2)) / 4096
        Utf8 = chr(&he0 + b3) & chr(&h80 + b2) & chr(&h80 + b1)
    End If

End Function
```

Just open a file with Scripting.FileSystemObject, using system default encoding. Then pass every character of the string you want to write through this function.

**NOTE** that the function expects a Unicode code point, so be sure to use `AscW()` instead of plain `Asc()`:

```
For i = 1 to Len(s)
    file.Write Utf8(AscW(Mid(s, i, 1)))
Next
```